# Redux Saga All effects proper usage

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I've started working with Redux-saga and I've been following the advanced section for composing sagas in parallel.
Currently this is the function that I'm using with `all` method, I need these to filter and transform some pages metadata before assigning to the Nav component.

```
    function* CreateNavFromPages(action) {
      const menu = action.payload.menu
      const menuPagesData = toList(menu.get('pages')).map(
        page => {
          const title = page.get('title');
          const uri = page.get('uri');

          return toPageData(title, uri);
        }
      );

      const staticPagesData = menuPagesData.filter(p => p.get('kind') === 'static');
      const pages = yield all(
        staticPagesData.map(page => backend(PagesApi, page.get('id')))
      );

      console.log(pages);
      const staticPagesMetadata = pages
        .filter(({ result, err }) => !err && result.items.length > 0)
        .map(result => fromJS(buildMetadata(fromJs(result.items[0]))));

      const pagesMetadata = menuPagesData.map(page => {
        const key = staticPagesMetadata.findIndex(el => findPage(el, id));
        if (key) {
         return staticPagesMetadata[key].copy({data: page.get('data')});
        }
        return page;
      });

      const nav = Immutable.Map({
        position: 'top',
        target: 'home',
        pagesMetadata
      });

     const {result, err} = yield backend(Navs.create, nav);
     if (err) { ...}
     else {
       yield put(NavActions.createNavSuccessful(result.nav));
      return true;
     }
    }

    function findPage(el, id) {
      return el.get('id') === id;
    }

   backend.js
   export default function* backend(...args) {
     try {
       return { result: yield call(...args)};
     }
     catch (e) {...}
   }

   pages_api.js
   .....
   function get(id) {
     return fetch('/api/pages/${id}');
   }

   export default {get}
```

When I run this on my App, I get the following error:

```
 uncaught at watchMany 
 at takeLatest(CREATE_NAV, createNavFromPages) 
 at createNavFromPages 
 TypeError: pages.filter is not a function
```

When checking console.log, I see the following:

```
 {size: 2, _origin: 0, _capacity: 2, _level: 5, _root: null, _tail: {Array(2){Generator, Generator}}}
```

Is there something I'm missing here? 
**UPDATED**: Added PagesApi definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests the problem is here:

```
const pages = yield all(
  staticPagesData.map(page => backend(PagesApi, page.get('id')))
);
```

The `all` effect expects a native javascript array as input parameter, however you are passing down Immutable list (which is the return type of `staticPagesData.map`).

Since the `all` effect doesn't understand Immutable.js lists it treats it as any other object - that is it resolves to the object itself, which is what you see in your `console.log` message.

To fix it you can e.g. convert the immutable list to javascript array like so:

```
const pages = yield all(
  staticPagesData.map(page => backend(PagesApi, page.get('id'))).toJS()
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the initial issue. However, now I get the following error:
`uncaught at check call: argument [object Object] is not a function` for each backend call.

Comment: I've tried the following `call(backend, PagesApi, page.get('id'))` but still seeing the same error.

Comment: Is `PagesApi` a function?

Comment: Yes it is. I found the problem after reading over several redux-saga issues. https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1018